# Java/Netbeans -- Reference a jTextfield dynamically?

Tags: java, netbeans, dynamic, jtextfield

Not sure if this is even remotely possible, but...

I have a jFrame with 10 different Textfields. Elequently named tf1, tf2, tf3...

What I'd LOVE to do is be able to reference them dynamically. Something like:

```
int i = 1;

while (i<11) {
    tf[i].settext("blah - " + i);
}
```

Any ideas? If anybody knows of a working example it'd be great.

Comment: why not store the 10 textFields in an array at the program start ? this code will work if the array name is "tf"

Comment: I really have no idea how to do that... I mean I can work with arrays (ie: String, int, doubles...), but are you talking about creating an array of textFields at runtime or somehow storing the existing textFields on my panel in an array?

Comment: `I can work with arrays (ie: String, int, doubles...),` - so why would an Array of JTextFields be any different? `are you talking about creating an array of textFields at runtime` - well if you want to work with an array (of any type) then you need to create the Array. So you create the Array,  use a loop to create the text field and add the text field to the Array and the panel.

Comment: Hey thanks for that. Between your description and the answer below, I'm pretty sure I can work it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the text of all the textfields in a JFrame:

```
Component ca[] = getContentPane().getComponents();
System.out.println("ca = " + Arrays.toString(ca));
int i = 0;
for(Component c: ca) {
    if(JTextField.class.isAssignableFrom(c.getClass())) {
        JTextField tf = (JTextField) c;
        tf.setText("blah -"+(++i));
    }
}
```